# how to display video thumbnail using HTML5?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to display a video list on left side Panel and when I click on video, video need to be play right side panel.

Left side panel has videos List in thumbnail format.

I want to implement this using HTML5 and jQuery plug-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link is helpful to you.
    http://css.flepstudio.org/en/jquery/html5-video-player-with-playlist-xml-driven.html

there is an xml file contains the url of videos (for playlist) and js file to parse the xml and then it ll display in a php page. You can additionally add thumbnail path in thexml file then get it throught javascript file. This tutorial will give you an idea to implement your task.